# Get hidden layer outputs

Tags: mxnet

I make a densenet network from gluon.vision

```
densenet = vision.densenet121(pretrained=True, ctx=mx.cpu())
```

I want to get the outputs of each convolutionnal layer (after a prediction), to plot them afterwards (features maps).
I can't do `densenet.get_internals()` (as I saw on internet and Github), as my network is not a Symbol but a HybridBlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution in mxnet forum :
[Gluon, get features maps of a CNN](https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/gluon-pretrained-model-layer-access-and-usage/772/2)

Actually, you have to transform the gluon model to a symbol using methods `export()` to save parameters (method from HybridBlock), and `mx.sym.load()` to load them.

function get_interals()["name_of_the_layer"] get all the layers from begining to this layer, so you can do `feat_maps = net(image)` to get all the features maps for this layer.

Then you can do a SummaryWriter in mxBoard to export it to Tensorboard.